# How to add Monthly Revenues from all the sheets named as Months/Year

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am working on the company dashboard using GSheets and I have different sheet tabs that are automatically duplicated and renamed at the end of the current month(using script) to save all the values required for revenue calculation.

The problem is to create a table that shows monthly revenue on a running basis (see image below). The issue I am facing here is to sum all the revenues from a particular month(sheet tabs) and place them in this table corresponding to the month(Cell A under Sums tab). Also, as the dates change it should automatically pick up the total revenue from the particular month tab and place it to the corresponding month in the table(Sums).

[Revenue/Month]//i.stack.imgur.com/xyHVo.png

The dates in the Revenue/Month table change dynamically based on the Month we are in(used formula- eomonth()).

Your help would be highly appreciated, I have attached the sheet for reference.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11jVixf2ho5YihgmhKPQV-eQ5LWcJYk_cQNStQMOF_hQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: [https://imgur.com/pxpFfpI.png](https://imgur.com/pxpFfpI.png)

Comment: Aman, welcome!  You have provided a link to your sheet, but not given us access. 
 Please see this guide to share your sheet correctly: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/3808684?hl=en

Comment: Better yet don’t depend on an external link to provide information about your question. Please put everything we need to answer your question in your question And don’t depend on external links because many of us like me wont answer your question if I have to follow links to the spreadsheet.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the heads up! I tried to be very clear in the above question and provided the link just for reference. Hope it helps @kirkg13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this formula helps you.  I've added a tab, [GKSums](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11jVixf2ho5YihgmhKPQV-eQ5LWcJYk_cQNStQMOF_hQ/edit#gid=57388756&range=B3), to your sample sheet.

```
=IFERROR(QUERY(INDIRECT("'" & TEXT(A3,"yyyy-mm") & "'!B2:G"),
           "select sum(G) where G>0 label sum(G) ''",0),"No Data")
```

This uses the date values in column B as the tab names (using INDIRECT) to sum the revenue from each tab.

At the moment, you have the same data in all the tabs, including multiple dates.  I assume that you will only have 2020-08 data in the 2020-08 tab, when you are finished.  But if you like, it is possible to add a date check in that query formula as well.  I may do that and provide an update here later.

### Update

To always include the current month, plus the previous 11 months, I adjusted the formula in GKSums!B14 from:

```
=IFERROR(QUERY(INDIRECT("'" & TEXT(A14,"yyyy-mm") & "'!B2:G"),
           "select sum(G) where G>0 label sum(G) ''",0),"No Data")
```

to

```
=IFERROR(QUERY(Campaigns!B2:G,
           "select sum(G) where G>0 label sum(G) ''",0),"No Data")
```

So instead of using an indirect reference based on the date, this justs looks for the tab named Campaigns, and queries the same data as the previous formulas.

Note the increase in the range, from B2:G to B2:I, to use your two additional columns.

**Closed Deals Count:**

Also, to count the number of deals in a month, instead of the sum of sales, use the following formula (see [GKSums column F-H](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11jVixf2ho5YihgmhKPQV-eQ5LWcJYk_cQNStQMOF_hQ/edit#gid=57388756&range=F1)):

```
=IFERROR(QUERY(INDIRECT("'" & TEXT(F3,"yyyy-mm") & "'!B2:I"),
           "select count(I) where G>0 label count(I) ''",0),"No Data")
```

You might consider conditional formatting to shade the cells green, if an increase in deals (or sales amounts) over the previous month, or red if a decrease.  Or add a column to show the percent increase or decrease.

**FORMULA Breakdown:**

Here is a detailed breakdown of one of the formulas:

```
=IFERROR(QUERY(INDIRECT("'" & TEXT(F13,"yyyy-mm") & "'!B2:I"),
           "select count(I) where G>0 label count(I) ''",0),"No Data")
```

This is considered a QUERY formula.  But instead of just giving a range to the `QUERY`, as in `=QUERY(A1:C99,...)` it needs to build the range dynamically, because the sheet name will change every month.  Since we want the data from twelve months ago, today that will be from a different sheet than it was last month.

The way we get the sheet name is by using the adjacent column, column A of F, which lists the last twelve months.  So `TEXT(F13,"yyyy-mm")` gets the date - which is a number value - from F13, and formats it as yyyy-mm, which is the text format you are using for naming your data tabs.   This gives us our sheet name (for one month).

If you put `="'" & TEXT(F13,"yyyy-mm") & "'!B2:I"` into a cell, that will equal: `'2020-12'!B2:I` which is our desired range.

To make that into the range, for the query, we need to use `INDIRECT`, since we are building a string equivalent of our range.

That gives us the `QUERY('2020-12'!B2:I,` part of our formula.

The criteria for the `QUERY` is:

```
"select count(I) where G>0 label count(I) ''"
```

This says return the total count of values in column I, for the rows where column G is > 0, ie. has a revenue value.  And make the label for the "`count(I)`" function blank - otherwise it defaults to "count".

Lastly, we wrap the whole query in an `IFERROR` function, to avoid errors, such as when you don't have a tab sheet for one of the months, eg 2020-02.  If an error results from the `QUERY`, we return "No Data", though it is possible there was some other error.

[image]

Comment: Lovely stuff, thanks alot it works flawless :)

Comment: I have another issue that just popped after I fully deployed the sheet. Its that in the table the revenue for the current month will only get recorded if a new sheet is created (renamed as 2021-01) but I would like to have the current month's revenue recorded from the first sheet always(named as Campaigns). Could you please help with this as well?

Comment: I have added a new tab(Campaigns) in the same sheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11jVixf2ho5YihgmhKPQV-eQ5LWcJYk_cQNStQMOF_hQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Also, can the same logic be applied to count the number of entries in the same month?

Comment: Hey @Kirkg13 thanks a ton! I corrected the date error, thanks!
Could you briefly explain the working behind this formula? "=IFERROR(QUERY(INDIRECT("'" & TEXT(F13,"yyyy-mm") & "'!B2:I"),
           "select count(I) where G>0 label count(I) ''",0),"No Data")"
Have never worked on this complex function. Thanks again!

Comment: Knocking at your door again! Is it possible to count the entries only for the current month and call the value in the table - Deals Closed. So for example- There are 2-3 records that were closed in January(mentioned under column I in campaigns sheet). And similarly the values get updated in the Deals closed table - GKSums based on the months mentioned. Hope its clear, I have updated all the Columns I

Comment: Thank you! @Kirkg13. There is one last thing I need to add to this deals count. I want to segregate the table based on Inbound/Outbound. So, counting the deals closed in the current month and segregating them based on Inbound/Outbound. I tried changing J=Inbound in the formula but that doesn't work, will appreciate this alot. Thanks in advance. (Done necessary changes in the sheet, added a new table)

Comment: My apologies @Kirkg13. Updated the columns in the Revs sheet. Actually as mentioned I want to have a view of deals closed in a month but segregated by Inbound deals and Outbound deals. If you look at the new table, you can see a segregated view of deals closed - Inbound and Outbound for each month. Hope its clear now? So, again I want to count the Deals Closed(as done before for subsequent months) but with a breakup of Inbounds and Outbounds for the subsequent month. Thanks!!!

Comment: Aman, updated the formulas.  Hope that's okay now.

Comment: Hi @Kirkg13, thanks for the new updates. I don't really get the Row(G5) function, and I used it on the actual sheet but doesn't work. Could you please help me?
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KrhZj_gWQxHfEFNAkPQTo7EQyoLsj897lQ7aa0QgkLg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hey buddy! Do you think you help? @kirkg13

Comment: Aman, the IF(ROW(G5)<>21 is now wrong, because you've moved the formula.  It should be IF(ROW(G5)<>15, because row(15) is now the row with the Campaign month in I15.  And you've add a column to the Campaigns tab, so that broke the formula.  I've fixed it again, on your sheet.